# EXTJS 6 Grid Column Renderer Function - where do you define it?

Tags: extjs, renderer

In EXTJS 4/5 you could create an inline function which you could then use as a grid column renderer, like this

```
function myColumnRenderer(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
    //do something with the data and return
    return value;
}
```

and in your grid's column definition you would reference the renderer like this

```
columns:[
{ text: 'ColA',  dataIndex: 'ColA', renderer: myColumnRenderer},
{ text: 'ColB',  dataIndex: 'ColB', renderer: myColumnRenderer}
]
```

In EXTJS 6.5, can you still do this and if so where do you define the renderer function?  In the controller, or viewModel, or elsewhere?  I've tried putting the function in the controller and putting this.myColumnRenderer in the renderer of the column but it never seems to get called.

Looks like this is an option, just not sure if it's the correct way to do it

```
columns:[
{ text: 'ColA',  dataIndex: 'ColA', renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                                                   return this.getController().myColumnRenderer(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                                              }},
{ text: 'ColB',  dataIndex: 'ColB', renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                                                   return this.getController().myColumnRenderer(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                                              }}
]
```

Comment: This is why I hate MVC. You are arbitrarily partitioning a thing in two, depending on what you think is view and what is logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **ExtJS 6** you can also create but inline `function` but instead of inline function we can create [`ViewController`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html) for `grid` or any `view` like below example

```
Ext.define('MyViewController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.myview',

    // This method is called as a "handler" for the Add button in our view
    onAddClick: function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Add', 'The Add button was clicked');
    }
});

Ext.define('MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    controller: 'myview',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add',
        handler: 'onAddClick',  // calls MyViewController's onAddClick method
    }]
});
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ds4)**, I have create a demo using `viewController` and `grid` component. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('GridController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.gridcntr',
            //This event will fire for grid column renderer
            onColRender: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                console.log(value);
                return value;
            }
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'grid',
            controller: 'gridcntr',
            title: 'user data',

            store: store,

            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                width: 200,
                renderer: 'onColRender'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                width: 250,
                renderer: 'onColRender'
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                width: 120,
                renderer: 'onColRender'
            }],


            layout: 'fit',
            fullscreen: true,
            renderTo:Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I figured it'd be something simple.  I had my renderer function in my viewController, but I didn't have single quotes around the function name when referencing it in the column config.  I just needed to change `renderer: myColumnRenderer` to `renderer: 'myColumnRenderer'`.  Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with this... there is a performance issue with defining the renderers in the controller.  See [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j24).  Basically the inline approach does not re-run when a change is made to a cell (through cell edit or if you have a check column and you change it).  The controller renderer does re-run every time, which can cause quite a bit of lag if you're checking all check columns programmatically.

Comment: Yes I have seen this. the controller `renderer` re-run in 6.2 and later on version. Need be check some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the renderer like this ExtJs 6

```
columns: [
            { width:"100%", renderer: function(value,metaData,records,view) {

                //your conditions
}}]
```